# Separate batch of xml using vb6

Tags: xml, vb6

I have a downloaded xml file with several main nodes repeated, how do I separate these nodes into different xml files, using vb6.

This is an example of the xml I'm working with:

```
<produto>
   <item>
    <codigo>001</codigo>
    <qtde>1</qtde>
   </item>
</produto>

<produto>
   <item>
    <codigo>002</codigo>
    <qtde>33</qtde>
   </item>
</produto>

<produto>
   <item>
    <codigo>004</codigo>
    <qtde>10</qtde>
   </item>
</produto>

<produto>
   <item>
    <codigo>005</codigo>
    <qtde>6</qtde>
   </item>
</produto>
```

I tried using the following code:

```
Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim noList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode


xmldoc.loadXML("C:\\test.xml")

Set noList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("produto")
For i = 0 To noList.length - 1
    '
    Set node = noList.Item(i)
    xmldoc.loadXML node.nodeValue

    strFile = "Arq_" & i & ".xml"

    node.Save strFile
    '
Next
```

But there was an error on the line: `Set noList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("produto")`

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed. It is missing it's root element

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this is not a well-formed XML file, missing a root node. Your XML currently has 4 route nodes `produto`.

So insert a root node, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <produto>
         <item>
            <codigo>001</codigo>
            <qtde>1</qtde>
         </item>
    </produto>
    <produto>
         <item>
            <codigo>002</codigo>
            <qtde>33</qtde>
         </item>
    </produto>
    <produto>
         <item>
            <codigo>004</codigo>
            <qtde>10</qtde>
         </item>
    </produto>
    <produto>
         <item>
            <codigo>005</codigo>
            <qtde>6</qtde>
         </item>
    </produto>
</root>
```

I also personally prefer `.selectNodes()` over `.getElementsByTagName()`. It uses a [XPath expression](https://devhints.io/xpath), which gives you more control over the selected elements. Not in this particular example, but in general. E.g. for the above example

```
Set noList = xmldoc.selectNodes("//root/produto")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

1. As mentioned, you must add a root node to your xml file.
2. You need to use `xmldoc.Load` when loading the downloaded file.
3. You need to use `node.xml` when loading the new document.
4. You need to use `xmldoc.save` when saving the new document.

With these changes in place, the code will work like you want:

```
xmldoc.Load "C:\test.xml"
Set noList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("produto")

For i = 0 To noList.length - 1
   Set node = noList.Item(i)
   xmldoc.loadXML node.xml

   strFile = "Arq_" & i & ".xml"

   xmldoc.save strFile
Next
```